# MomentJS UTC date is not detected as utc inside momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a date represented as a string:

```
const dateStr = "2022-09-29T00:00:00Z";
```

So this is UTC format with zero (equivalent to `"2022-09-29T00:00:00+0000"`)

When I use momentJS it is converted to my local time(and this is fine), but my local time -3 hours, so by this example I have `22-09-28`, this happens because momentJs doesn't recognize it as UTC, but it is UTC format - why?
Please see the screenshot attached below, I mean `_isUTC` flag

[image]

Code I am testing below:

```
const dateStr = "2022-09-29T00:00:00Z";
const res = moment(dateStr)
const res1 = moment(dateStr).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // will be 2022-09-28 because of -3 hours my timezone and it is not detected as UTC.
console.log(res);
```

P.S. I know that `moment(dateStr).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD')` will work but can it be detected automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While moment *recognizes* the input as a UTC date, it will still be converted to local time when using moment().

> Moment's string parsing functions like moment(string) and moment.utc(string) accept offset information if provided, but convert the resulting Moment object to local or UTC time.

I'd suggest using [`UTC mode`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/), using the moment.utc() function, or using moment().utc().

> While in UTC mode, all display methods will display in UTC time instead of local time.

This should give you the desired behavior:

```js
const dateStr = "2022-09-29T00:00:00Z";
const dtUTC = moment.utc(dateStr);

console.log('UTC mode:');
console.log('dtUTC.format():', dtUTC.format());
console.log('_.isUTC:', dtUTC ._isUTC);
console.log('UTC offset:', dtUTC .format('Z'));

// Using the moment() constructor, the date will be recognized as UTC but converted to the local timezone:
console.log('\nLocal:');
const dtLocal = moment(dateStr );
console.log('dtLocal.format():', dtLocal.format());
console.log('_.isUTC:', dtLocal._isUTC);
console.log('UTC offset:', dtLocal.format('Z'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```